# Python html parse

Tags: python, htmlparse

I am trying to extract DetailID value from the html for example view-source:http://www.hgtv.com/

```
mdManager.addParameter("DetailID", "466c141156dd2b88eeffedd780cf9126");
```

output should be `466c141156dd2b88eeffedd780cf9126`

i am currently using re.search and its takes a while to search 
Here is my code

```
searchObj = re.search( r'(.*)DetailID\",(\s\")(.*)(\"\))', html_source_code.text, re.M|re.I)
print(searchObj.group(3))
```

Is there a better way to get the result faster

Comment: PyQuery Is a real good module that let you use CSS selectors. If you'd like to try I could expand how to do it in as an answer

Comment: Thanks i think i found a simple solution,actually my reg exp has the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked

```
regex = re.compile(r'DetailID", "(.*)(\"\))')
detailId =  regex.search(source_code.text).group(1)
```